# Is there a word for a unique manufactured item?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms, uniquity

Is there a synonym for "unique" that specifically applies to a custom-made or customized item - say, a car - of which only one copy exists?

Something like "once-in-a-lifetime" but in the meaning of something like "only-one-in-the-world"?

Comment: Just combine the adjectives *unique* and *custom-made* to get: *"a unique, custom-made car"*. There's no need for a single word, and I don't believe one exists. Would you ask for a single word that meant *big* and *red*, so you wouldn't have to put two adjectives on *big, red house*?

Comment: _Bespoke_ is the UK version, though it normally applies only to personally tailored clothing.

Comment: *Bespoke* or *custom-made* don't mean *unique*, although something that is *bespoke* (or *custom-made*) will quite likely be unique.

Comment: **One-off** is used both adjectivally and nounally. At least [in the UK](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/07/04/magazine/04FOB-onlanguage-t.html).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, but *one-off* is a comparative newcomer to these cisatlantic shores. Previously it was strictly British, and still sounds somewhat foreign to my ears. The first OED citation is only from 1934, and all citations through the 1970s are strictly British. In America, it would be a *one-of-a-kind* widget. Sometimes, just a *one-time* thing works, too. There’s no working around the fact that *unique* has a **unique** meaning that has no one-word synonym in English, a word that’s truly *sui generis* in its uniquity. It’s the onliest word you’ll ever need, or have. :)

Comment: In the US, [*custom*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/custom) as an adjective is often used to mean just that.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/47013 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118105 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/144840 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110202 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/107490 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/113149 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/145236

Comment: John -- bespoke is very much used for cars (particularly *British* bespoke cars!) (you know, the German ones) and many other things, not just clothes.

Comment: Peter - your second comment is unusual.  You're asking does bespoke " ' mean ' " unique, or, is bespoke just the word that is used 100.00000% of the time, exactly and universally, in every commercial and private setting, by every single English speaker in every country (and indeed, additionally, every tourist shopper from China, Japan, etc! heh) to refer to, precisely, exactly, what the OP describes (where he happens to use "unique" in quotes, as well as other words, to try to describe what he is referring to).

Comment: Speaking as a 72-year-old US citizen who has never visited England, "one-off" is probably the most familiar term, with "one-of-a-kind" maybe a hair more familiar, but that latter expression doesn't really capture the degree of uniqueness.  "Bespoke" is familiar to most reasonably literate people in the US, but it's a bit pompous.

Answer (score 2):

For the record the answer to the question "Is there a word for a unique manufactured item?" is "Yes."  There are three terms:

One-off, custom, or bespoke.

All of these are used exactly, precisely, and commonly as you describe for exactly, precisely what you describe.

(Simply look on the web sites of companies that do precisely what you describe; whether custom car-makers in California, Mercedes' Designo workshop, Van Cleef on place vandome, or whatever.)

{Indeed it's hard to refer to, say, a custom kitchen maker, or a bespoke furniture studio, without using these common, well-known terms.}

(Sure, there are slight nuances of meaning and local favourites, but so what?)

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

- ***One-of-a-kind***
- ***Prototype***

Comment: But prototype suggests there will be more of the object, not necessarily but possibly the same.

Answer (score 1):

*Unicum* is what you are looking for. According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unicum):

> a unique example or specimen.

Answer (score -3):

Since you mentioned cars, it's worth knowing that the phrase ["concept car"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_car) is very close to what you're talking about. This is generally only used for motor vehicles, though. You might see "concept truck" or "concept bike," but not "concept suit" or "concept computer."

Comment: A concept car is an example of a custom-made item of which only one copy exists, but it's not the answer to the question. A concept car is a demonstration of what the company might be building in the future, to showcase new (or imagined) technology and styling. Most concept cars are unique but not all unique cars are concept cars.